# Retrieve the creator (user) and created date of a SharePoint group

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010

I need to find the user that created a SharePoint 2010 group as well as the date that it was created.  I have tried to find the information using the "SharePoint Manager 2010" tool, but it doesn't seem to provide such information. I also tried Powershell, but I can't seem to get it from that either (not very good at Powershell yet).

Is this even possible, or I would need to turn the audit on somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

There is no Way to get it as far as I know. Even via C# you can't get Values like `siteGroup["Author"]` or `siteGroup[Created"]`.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite("http://DemoSP2010"))
            {
                using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.RootWeb)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(spWeb.Title);
                    SPGroupCollection collection = spWeb.SiteGroups;
                    foreach (SPGroup siteGroup in collection)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(siteGroup.Owner.ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine(siteGroup.Xml.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Done!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The XML also just provides information about:

- ID
- Name
- Description
- OwnerID
- OwnerIsUser

Comment: Can you explain to me what ownerisuser means, I cannot find it in any docs, thanks

Comment: Owner is a principal in the first place. So it can be a User or the System Account or an AD Group (not sure anymore). Important to know is, that the System Account is no normal User. Super rights and no Email ;)

Answer (score 1):

(IDK about 2010 ...but) In SharePoint 2013 on-prem the following Powershell will provide the Created by, Created date, Modified by and Modified date of each group (and site user)

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell

$spWeb = Get-SPWeb 'http(s)://YourSite/'
$spList =$spWeb.SiteUserInfoList
$oColl = $spList.Items
$oColl | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_['ID'] $_['Name'] $_['Author'] $_['Created'] $_['Editor'] $_['Modified']
}
```